# Questions on Formal Education in Computer Science / Engineering

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is it acceptable to ask questions about formal education on Stack Overflow?  These are not technically "programming related" but it would seem to be a good for forum as long as they were restricted to computer science/engineering.

For instance,  I'm considering going back to grad school and would like to ask what schools are good for research in a particular area of computer science.  Surely this has more value than "Where is the bug in this code sample"?

Comment: You should do a search for that question.  I'm 80% sure it is already there.

Comment: @jjnguy Thanks, that question was more of an example. I have some more specific ones in mind.

Comment: Related: [Where would a question about education be on-topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253891/289691), [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/289691)

Answer (score 5):

This would be a rather subjective question - how many people have sufficient experience with multiple schools to actually provide a valid comparison? Potentially quite argumentative too, if there's such a thing as "school spirit" among CS grads...

I don't think you should ask it. If I saw it, I'd probably vote to close it.

But if you do ask it, please make it CW and provide some guidelines to help users avoid flamewars (for instance: one school per answer, edit to add your experiences, don't duplicate, leave editorials for comments).

Comment: +1: for making me feel like I'm not being unreasonable to vote to close these types of questions...

Answer (score 3):

Well there are 180 questions tagged [`education`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/education), on Stack Overflow.

There are also 601 questions tagged [`career-development`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/career-development).

Although it does look like a large number of them are Community Wiki questions.

Comment: Both of those tags have since been burninated.

Answer (score 3):

The questions have been asked quite a bit, but I tend to vote to close them as they are not a direct programming question which is the what SO is for.  If it is a a discussion question such as where to go to school, etc. META may be a better home.

Comment: I was wondering if maybe meta should be the home for these questions as well. I can see why it would be valuable to ask this type of question to the SO community; but I also understand why they are often closed, because they really aren't related to programming.

Comment: I don't think Meta is really appropriate either though because you aren't asking about SE.  Perhaps programmers?  I was about to ask this same question but ask "Where should I post...", not "Should I post on..."