# Where would a question about education be on-topic?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where would a question about the education system itself be on-topic?

No public SE sites seem to support the topic. Maybe there's a proposal on Area 51?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any SE sites that cover education as a whole, but [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) (which usually focuses on graduate/PhD-level education) and [MathEducators SE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) definitely cover parts of it. I also see Area51 proposals for [Science Educators](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79366/science-educators) and [Pedagogy](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/85577/pedagogy) (which is expected to cover "lower" levels of education than Academia SE). If you have a question that isn't covered by any of those, then it might be worth making a new Area51 proposal.

Comment: Pedagogy seems to cover my question. Thanks!

Comment: @DominatorX No problem. In fact, now that I've looked up all those sites, I wish Pedagogy was a real site already. Maybe I should follow it...